# How to get location updates at particular interval after application is killed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, background, location

I'm using [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) library to get location at every 10 sec. It is working properly when application is **ON** and when application is in recents of our phone but by this library I'm not able to get location updated after application is killed.